# Plotting a list of (lattitude, longitude, value)-tuples in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geocoding, matplotlib-basemap

I have a list of (latitude, logitude, value)-Tuples I want to show using Basmap. What's the easiest way to do that?

```
data = [(1, 2, 0.12323),
        (2, 5, 0.23232),
        (4, 52,0.23131)
        .
        . tenthousand times this.
        .
       ]
```

Comment: It would be useful if you added at least some mock data and any code you have already attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used basemap, but it looks like what you want is the scatter() method:

http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.scatter

Which takes the same parameters as the matplotlib.pyplot.scatter method:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter